# Type 'BaseContract & Omit<ContractInterface, keyof BaseContract>' is missing the following properties

Tags: typescript, solidity, hardhat, typechain

I'm using `@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox` v3.0.0 that uses ethers v6.

The below code works in ethers v5 with `@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox` v2.0.2

```
import { FundMe } from "./../../typechain-types"

describe("FundMe", async () => {
    let fundMe: FundMe

    beforeEach(async () => {

        const fundMeContract = await deployments.get("FundMe")

        fundMe = (await ethers.getContractAt(
            fundMeContract.abi,
            fundMeContract.address
        )) as FundMe
    })
})
```

With the new version, I'm getting the following error:

```
Conversion of type 'Contract' to type 'FundMe' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Type 'BaseContract & Omit<ContractInterface, keyof BaseContract>' is missing the following properties from type 'FundMe': attach, deployed, functions, MINIMUM_USD, and 9 more.
```

I've tried:

fundMe = await ethers.getContractAt(
fundMeContract.abi,
fundMeContract.address
)

And getting the error:

```
Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.ts(2558)
```

OR

```
fundMe = await ethers.getContractAt(
            fundMeContract.abi,
            fundMeContract.address
        )
```

And I get the error:

```
Type 'BaseContract & Omit<ContractInterface, keyof BaseContract>' is missing the following properties from type 'FundMe': attach, deployed, functions, MINIMUM_USD, and 9 more
```

What can I do to make it work with Typescript despite using the any type ?
The code works but VSCode is showing the error.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to include `typechain-types` directory into "tsconfig.json".

Here's a sample "tsconfig.json":

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2018",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "include": ["./scripts", "./test", "./typechain-types"],
  "files": ["./hardhat.config.ts"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. I'm using the workaround for now:

```
...
fundMe = (await (ethers as any).getContractAt(
...
```